# Merging a changing collection of observables

Tags: system.reactive

We have a class `Thing` that implements `IObservable<Thing>`. In another class, there is a collection of `Thing`s , and that class needs to react to updates from all those observables in a unified manner. The obvious way to do that is `Observable.Merge()`, and that generally works; *however*, when the collection changes, we also need to subscribe to any new `Thing`s in our merged subscription (and in theory unsubscribe from all the removed ones, but that seems less problematic - they just won't produce any updates anymore).

We currently achieve that by recreating the subscription on every change of the collection, but that seems rather suboptimal in terms of processing overhead and also due to missing updates from any of the `Thing`s in the brief time between discarding the old subscription and creating the new one (which has proven to be an issue in practice, especially as we also need to `Buffer()` the subscription for a short amount of time, and the buffered items are lost when disposing the subscription).

What is the proper way of merging a changing collection of observables like this?

Comment: What is the type of collection holding the Thing Observables?

Comment: @Shlomo Oh, I should have mentioned that. It's an `ObservableCollection` (more precisely a Caliburn.Micro `BindableCollection`).

Comment: I'm also assuming that you don't have `class Thing : IObservable<Thing>`, which would be rather trippy. Typo? Maybe you meant  `class Thing : IObservable<Thing2>` ?

Comment: No, it's actually `IObservable<Thing>`; every instance just notifies subscribers that *something* has happened to it, and this way the instances can later be identified again in the merged Observable.

Comment: I would recommend against implementing `IObservable<T>`. I would further recommend not doing `class Thing : IObservable<Thing>`. Seems like cruel and unusual punishment to inflict on your developer team mates.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `IObservable<IObservable<T>> observable`, then calling `Merge` on that, will include children of new parents, if you catch my drift. The trick is converting the `ObservableCollection<IObservable<Thing>>` to an `IObservable<IObservable<Thing>>`.

If you have ReactiveUI running around, and are ok to use it, then you could convert the `ObservableCollection<IObservable<Thing>>` to a `ReactiveCollection<IObservable<Thing>>`. `ReactiveCollection` inherits from `ObservableCollection`, and also implements `IObservable`.

If ReactiveUI is out of the question (which I'm guessing it is because you're already using a Caliburn Micro collection), then you can convert using `ObservableCollection`'s events:

```cs
ObservableCollection<IObservable<Thing>> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<IObservable<Thing>>();
IObservable<IObservable<Thing>> oCollectionObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
    h => observableCollection.CollectionChanged += h,
    h => observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= h
)
    .SelectMany(ep => ep.EventArgs.NewItems.Cast<IObservable<Thing>>());
```

Here's some sample code demonstrating use:

```cs
oCollectionObservable
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine($"Received Thing {{Id = {t.Id}}}"));

var firstObservable = Observable.Range(1, 5)
    .Select(i => new Thing { Id = i })
    .Concat(
        Observable.Range(8, 5)
            .Select(i => new Thing { Id = i })
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    );

observableCollection.Add(firstObservable);
var subject = new Subject<Thing>();
observableCollection.Add(subject);
subject.OnNext(new Thing { Id = 6 });
subject.OnNext(new Thing { Id = 7 });
```

Using the following class:

```cs
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```