# Merge events from a changing list of Observables

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm using `rxjs`.

I have a `Browser` that's responsible for a number of `Page` objects. Each page has an `Observable<Event>` that yields a stream of events.

`Page` objects are closed and opened at various times. I want to create one observable, called `TheOneObservable` that will merge all the events from all the currently active `Page` objects, and also merge in custom events from the `Browser` object itself.

Closing a `Page` means that the subscription to it should be closed so it doesn't prevent it from being GC'd.

My problem is that `Pages` can be closed at any time, which means that the number of Observables being merged is always changing. I've thought of using an Observable of `Pages` and using `mergeMap`, but there are problems with this. For example, a subscriber will only receive events of Pages that are opened after it subscribes.

---

Note that this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126773/merging-a-changing-collection-of-observables) for `.NET`, but using an `ObservableCollection` that isn't available in `rxjs`.

---

Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
class Page {
    private _events = new Subject<Event>();

    get events(): Observable<Event> {
        return this._events.asObservable();
    }
}

class Browser {
    pages = [] as Page[];
    private _ownEvents = new Subject<Event>();

    addPage(page : Page) {
        this.pages.push(page);
    }

    removePage(page : Page) {
        let ixPage = this.pages.indexOf(page);
        if (ixPage < 0) return;
        this.pages.splice(ixPage, 1);
    }

    get oneObservable() {
        //this won't work for aforementioned reasons
        return Observable.from(this.pages).mergeMap(x => x.events).merge(this._ownEvents);
    }
}
```

It's in TypeScript, but it should be understandable.

Comment: What have you tried? We need a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung I added some code, but I think it's not that important. It's not a case of "this code doesn't work", it's a case of "how do I do X using this technology". There isn't any code I've written that doesn't work, so that I can show it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `switchMap()` on a `Subject()` linked to array changes, replacing oneObservable with a fresh one when the array changes.

```js
pagesChanged = new Rx.Subject();

addPage(page : Page) {
  this.pages.push(page);
  this.pagesChanged.next();
}

removePage(page : Page) {
  let ixPage = this.pages.indexOf(page);
  if (ixPage < 0) return;
  this.pages.splice(ixPage, 1);
  this.pagesChanged.next();
}

get oneObservable() {
  return pagesChanged
    .switchMap(changeEvent =>
      Observable.from(this.pages).mergeMap(x => x.events).merge(this._ownEvents)
    )
}
```

Testing,

```js
const page1 = { events: Rx.Observable.of('page1Event') }
const page2 = { events: Rx.Observable.of('page2Event') }

let pages = []; 
const pagesChanged = new Rx.Subject();
const addPage = (page) => { 
  pages.push(page); 
  pagesChanged.next(); 
}
const removePage = (page) => { 
  let ixPage = pages.indexOf(page);
  if (ixPage < 0) return;
  pages.splice(ixPage, 1);
  pagesChanged.next(); 
}

const _ownEvents = Rx.Observable.of('ownEvent')

const oneObservable = 
  pagesChanged
    .switchMap(pp => 
      Rx.Observable.from(pages)
        .mergeMap(x => x.events)
        .merge(_ownEvents)
    )

oneObservable.subscribe(x => console.log('subscribe', x))

console.log('adding 1')
addPage(page1)
console.log('adding 2')
addPage(page2)
console.log('removing 1')
removePage(page1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a great method! However, don't you have to define `oneObservable` as `pagesChanged.startsWith(null)...`? Otherwise, it won't emit the events until you do at least one `addPage`, since a `switchMap` won't yield anything until the Observable you're switching on does.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Or probably `const pagesChanged = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manage the subscriptions to the pages yourself and feed its events into the resulting subject yourself:

```
const theOneObservable$ = new Subject<Event>();

function openPage(page: Page): Subscription {
  return page.events$.subscribe(val => this.theOneObservable$.next(val));
}
```

Closing the page, i.e. calling `unsubscribe` on the returned subscription, will already do everything it has to do.

> Note that `theOneObservable$` is a hot observable here.

You can, of course, take this a bit further by writing your own observable type which encapsulates all of this API. In particular, this would allow you to unsubscribe all inner observables when it is being closed.

---

A slightly different approach is this:

```
const observables$ = new Subject<Observable<Event>>();
const theOneObservable$ = observables$.mergeMap(obs$ => obs$);

// Add a page's events; note that takeUntil takes care of the
// unsubscription process here.
observables$.next(page.events$.takeUntil(page.closed$));
```

This approach is superior in the sense that it will unsubscribe the inner observables automatically when the observable is unsubscribed.